# Observable property assigned in SceneDelegate turns to nil

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my `SceneDelegate` I assign the variable of `UserInfo()` `token`:

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    @ObservedObject var userInfo = UserInfo()

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("ERROR fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
      } else if let result = result {
        print("REMOTE instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        self.userInfo.token = result.token
      }
    }
```

**Model.swift**

```
class UserInfo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var token: String? = nil{
        didSet(newValue){
            print("NEW value:\(newValue)")
        }
        
    }
}
```

`print("NEW value:\(newValue)")` then successfully prints the new value. However, when I access `token` in another model, it is `nil`:

```
class Search: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    lazy var functions = Functions.functions()
    let settings = UserSettings()
    @ObservedObject var userInfo = UserInfo()
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @Published var status = Status.offline
    
    func getUserData() -> [String:Any?]? {
        guard let birthday = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "birthday"), let latitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, let longitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude else {
            print("BDAY \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "birthday"))")
            print("LOCATION \(locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)")
            print("TOKEN \(self.userInfo.token)") // prints nil
            return nil
        }
        guard let fcmToken = self.userInfo.token else {
            return nil
        }
```

Why is this? `userInfo.token` is only assigned once at app startup in `SceneDelegate` - so I'm not sure why it's value changes to `nil`. Unless there are multiple instances of `UserInfo()` - however I thought `ObservableObject` would make it "one source of truth'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: `@ObservedObject` has sense only within SwiftUI `View`, so just remove that wrapper from your classes.

2nd: Your `SceneDelegate` and `Search` create *different* instances of `UserInfo`, so it is obvious that changing one of them does not affect anyhow another one.

Solution: it is not clear from provided snapshot how `Search` can refer to `SceneDelegate`, but you have *to inject* `SceneDelegate.userInfo` into `Search` somehow in place of creation latter (either by constructor argument or by assigning property)